# change the timestamp to next coming month and keeping the date as it is

Tags: php, datetime

I want to change the my date saved in database if the date saved in table s 1403222400 i.e. 06/19/2014(m/d/y format)

i want to change the month to next month(August not july becoz july has been completed) but want to keep the date  same.
i have tried using

$NextPaymentDate = strtotime('+1 month','140322240');

i have tried using this but it adds one month to the timestamp but there might be possibilty that the one month that has been added is already completed so I Want to add the coming month and date.

can any body help me? how to get the next coming month?

-------------------update code---------------

```
FORMAT="m/d/Y";
       $newPaymentDate=date(FORMAT,"1401926400"); 
            $date = new DATETIME($newPaymentDate);      
                $NextPaymentDate = $date->modify("+1 year");
                      $year = date("Y");
                      $NextPaymentDate = $date->format("m/d/".$year );
                      if(strtotime('now') > strtotime($NextPaymentDate))
                       {
                      $new_date = new DATETIME($NextPaymentDate);
                     $NextPaymentDate = $new_date->modify("+1 year");
                      $NextPaymentDate = $new_date->format(FORMAT);
         }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *completed*.?

Comment: You mean if it's 30th January, you want to jump straight to 30th March because there is no 30th February?

Comment: P5Coder completed means the month of this year that already gone
@markBaker yes exactly.. 
and if it's 18jan and present month is august but 18 Aug has gone than it should be 18 sep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the int to date format... By using

```
$new=date('Y-m-d',1403222400);
    $date = new DATETIME($new);
    $NextPaymentDate = $date->modify("+1 month");
    $n =date("m");
    $NextPaymentDate = $date->format("Y-".$n."-d");
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    if(strtotime($today) > strtotime($NextPaymentDate))
    {
        $new_date = new DATETIME($NextPaymentDate);
        $NextPaymentDate = $new_date->modify("+1 month");
        $NextPaymentDate = $new_date->format("Y-m-d");
    }
```

Hopefully this will help :)

Comment: its not workking coz to use $NextPaymentDate = strtotime('+1 month',$new);

$new should be in timestamp not in date format

Comment: 1403222400= 06/19/2014(M/d/y)
and your function returns  07/19/2014 but july is already completed and 19 aug is also gone than in this case this should show  09/19/2014

Comment: yes.. and if we have month 18/june than how we will check the current month and date and update it to 18/sep coz 18/Aug is already gone

Comment: does it met your requirement?

Comment: can you mark this as answer if it met your requirement :)

Comment: can you please tell me how to use above code in m/d/Y format.. coz when I try with m/d/Y format  to increase year same as did for month than it gives wrong month.
but if i user format it gives the exact result

Comment: $NextPaymentDate = $new_date->modify("+1 year");
try this

Comment: create a new question? You cant have two answers for one question :)